# Can't compile for a package

Tags: apex, package

When trying to create or open a package in Salesforce I get the following error:

> Bad References Found
> Please press Recompile All or edit and resave the following items
> « Back to Package List
>
> 30f7F000000A73q
> 30f7F000000A73r

YES! I have pressed "Recompile All"

Salesforce support have asked me a around 5 times to press the button, and of course I did that before submitting tickets.

Any ideas at all? I assume some process builder or apex was deleted and it's stuck in a cache or something, beyond me.

Comment: The object in reference is InteractionFormula I don't know what that is. But it starts with 30f

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce finally found the error. There was a compile bug on a flow. Who was to know. I couldn't resave it and just redid part of it.